# Update Data From A Table With a Complicate Predicas

Tags: sql, t-sql

I Have `TableA`(`A1`,`A2`) and `TableB`(`B1`,`B2`)
Suppose

```
TableA
(1,x)
(1,y)
(1,z)
(2,e)

TableB
(1,xx)
(1,yy)
(1,xx)
(3,ff)
```

I want to update `TableA.A2` with column `TableB.B2`
how can i do that

```
UPDATE TableA
SET A2 = B2
From TableA join TableB on A1=B1
```

dosn't work
results is:

```
TableA
(1,xx)
(1,xx)
(1,xx)
(2,e)
```

The result i'm looking for is:

```
TableA
(1,xx)
(1,yy)
(1,xx)
(2,e)
```

Comment: Rows (and columns) do not have any inherent order. You need to find something in your rows (other columns?) such that the mapping between tableA and tableB is 1-1. Otherwise, SQL Server is free to do whatever it likes (as in this case, where it's decided that both rows in A match the (1,xx) row in B).

Comment: My understanding was that, in cases such as these, each record is actually updated multiple times.  It's simply that SQL Server arbitrarily decides which order the updates happen, and so you can't predict which will come last (and so be the one that you see)?

Comment: @Dems - whether it actually performs multiple updates or a single update is a fairly opaque implementation detail (other than that, in the UPDATE trigger, each row will only appear once each in `inserted` and `deleted`, similarly for an `OUTPUT` clause), and "last" is indeed poorly defined (such that I wouldn't even include it when describing what's occurring).

Answer (score 1):

```
;with cteB as
(
  select *,
         row_number() over(partition by B1 order by (select 1)) as rn
  from TableB
),
cteA as
(
  select *,
         row_number() over(partition by A1 order by (select 1)) as rn
  from TableA
)
update A set
  A2 = B.B2
from cteA as A
  inner join cteB as B
    on A.A1 = B.B1 and
       A.rn = B.rn
```

This will produce the desired output for your sample data and table structure. But as others have said and as @Dems pointed out in a comment,  you have no control over what row is updated. This update statement will create the keys needed for the update every time you run it and since the `order by` clause is `select 1` the order of the updates can be different between each run.

Comment: This doesn't resolve the problem that you could run this 10 times and get different results each time.  Sure, each record in TableA is updated with respect to on record in TableB, but you wouldn't be able to pre-determine which record that would be...

Comment: @Dems – The final result for this sample data and table structure will be the same every time. They have no internal order until you query TableA with an order by so it really does not matter if the first record in TableA is updated with the first record of TableB every time or not.

Comment: For this exact sample set, you are right.  But he already includes an example of `group 2` existing in one table, and not the other, and vice versa for `group 3`.  If this can be true, I'd venture that the group sizes may be able to vary as well, at which point everything changes.  Additionally, the formulation of the question is trivialised, we don't know if other fields exist (which is possible, and I'd guess likely), causing each record to be unique rather than similies.  I would just prefer this answer to be loaded with caveats rather than the OP thinking he hit a panacea ;)

Comment: @Dems – Updated answer trying to explain what is going on here. Please feel free to add/modify if I'm not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

It possibly looks like your UPDATE is correct, but that your data is incorrect.

Both tables have `1` in the first field of both records.  This means that when you join the two tables together, each record in the first table matches Both records in the second table.

Do you mean to have a `1` in the first record, and a `2` in the second record?

**EDIT**

Expanding on what Damien mentioned, you need to change the join such that only one record from TableB is matched to each record in TableA.  How you do that depends on what you are trying to achieve.  An example based on your example data...

```
UPDATE
  TableA
SET
  B1 = TableB.B1
FROM
  TableA
INNER JOIN
  TableB
    ON  TableA.A1 = TableB.A1
    AND LEFT(TableA.B1, 1) = LEFT(TableB.B1, 1)
```

Using only A1 in your join isn't enough, but I'm also guessing you don't want to use B1 in the join.

In which case you need to add another field to the tables.  Some kind of information that you can use to say "this record from TableA matches to that ONE record in TableB".

Only when your data and query specifically state a one-to-one relationship will you get your desired result.  So here is the question:
- **How do *you* know which record in TableB needs to be copied to which record in TableA?**

**EDIT**

Thanks for your edit.  Unfortunately it doesn't change anything : SQL tables have no 'natural' order to them.

Although you may have inserted the data in that order, and maybe it even normally comes back like that when selected, it's not guaranteed.  There is no way of saying "relate the first record from TableA to the first record from TableB" because the order is not guatanteed and so "first" means nothing.

You *must*, I'm afraid, add an extra column to each table.  If you can write `SELECT * FROM TableA ORDER BY NewColumn(s)`, and get the data in the order you want, it's possible to solve.  If you can't do it with an ORDER BY, it's not possible to solve in a way that will always put the same values against the same records.

Comment: i m loking for this result
'TableA
(1,xx)
(1,yy)
'
what script do i have to execute

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever : yes, but in my case its complicate to do so

Comment: "How do you know which record in TableB needs to be copied to which record in TableA?"

i have only one column to match my to tables; all the other columns ill be updated with at least three joined other tables. 

so what i want to do is, the first row of Table1 my be updated with the first row of RESULT_OF_JOINTURES the second with the second...
'UPDATE TableA
SET A2 = B2
From RESULT_OF_JOINTURES'

Comment: SQL has no implicit order of records.  There is no such thing as the *guaranteed* first record.  You could query it with a SELECT and get (1,xx) first, then when you do something else (1,yy) could be first. Instead you *must* give each record a field by which the table can be ordered by, and so be able to use that field in your join.

Answer (score 0):

In case of your join coloumns having unique records:

```
UPDATE
    TableA
SET
a2 = (select TableB.b2 from TableB where TableA.a1=TableB.b1)
WHERE EXISTS
(select TableB.b2 from TableB where  TableA.a1=TableB.b1)
```

Comment: This doesn't help.  TableB still has two matching records for each record in TableB.  Until he estalishes a mechanism to relate the tables on a 1:1 relationship, he can't guarantee what will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Your updated example doesn't help. You say you have TableB:

```
(1,xx)
(1,yy)
(1,xx)
(3,ff)
```

But, you really don't. So far as SQL is concerned, this is the same as:

```
(1,xx)
(1,xx)
(1,yy)
(3,ff)
```

or:

```
(1,yy)
(1,xx)
(1,xx)
(3,ff)
```

or even:

```
(1,yy)
(1,xx)
(3,ff)
(1,xx)
```

That is to say, rows do not have any kind of ordering. You need some other columns in this table (and TableA) to allow the rows from one table to be matched uniquely with rows in another table.